# Why does my dog love her furry toys?

Tags: dogs, behavior

We have a 3 year old desexed greyhound. She was brought up in kennels with other greyhounds for the first two years of her life.

Whenever we've been out and come home and sometimes when we're getting ready she'll get one of her furry toys and carry it around the house in her mouth.

She's always happy and excited when she does this, wagging her tail and she looks so cute. She reminds me of a little children.

I'm wondering why she does this?

I'm not looking for people's opinions, I'm wondering if there's been any research on this.

A pic of our dog with her favourite toys - she had taken them out onto the balcony with her and then brought them back inside when she came back inside.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is just one of the natural prey drive behaviors that comes naturally to many dogs. It's a behavior more typical of the retriever group of dog breeds, which are selectively bred specifically for the job of following their master when they go hunting, then retrieving and carrying the kill back. But due to natural variation, it seems your Greyhound has turned out with more of the desire to retrieve and carry than is typical for a greyhound, which are normally bred for a strong chase instinct.